# Is it possible to integrate Google Firebase Analytics to React Native Expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I want to integrate `Google Firebase Analytics` to my React Native Expo app,
preferably but not limited to using the `react-native-firebase` library.

I'm trying to add such plugin configuration to my `app.json` file:

```
...
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "@react-native-firebase/perf",
      "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics",
      "@react-native-firebase/analytics"
    ]
...
```

After `npx expo install @react-native-firebase/analytics` I'm receiving this message:
`Skipping config plugin check: Package "@react-native-firebase/analytics" does not contain a valid config plugin`.

In `react-native-firebase` docs I found this information:

> Not all React Native Firebase packages have Expo config plugins provided yet. You may see if a module is supported by checking if it contains the app.plugin.js file in its package directory.

This applies to the analytics package.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Config plugins allow you to make changes to the native project files in the `ios` and `android` folders.

For example the performance module requires adding code to the `/android/build.gradle` file.

The analytics package does not need any native code changes and does not need a config plugin.

You can simply remove the `@react-native-firebase/analytics` line from the plugins array and analytics will still work.

```
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "@react-native-firebase/perf",
      "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics"
    ]
```